# Only show array elements if it is present in another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two array:

```
$array_1 = array
(
    0 => 12,
    1 => 14,
    2 => 18
);

$array_2 = array
(
    0 => 13,
    1 => 14,
    2 => 22
);
```

I need only elements which is present in both array. 
I've tried `array_intersect` but didn't get desired output.

```
$result = array_intersect($array_1, $array_2);
$result = !empty($result);
print_r($result);
```

It is giving output `1` instead of `14`.

Comment: According to you, desired output must be 14?

Comment: yes @NanaPartykar

Comment: What do you think `!empty` does…?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is perfectly fine.

Just remove the line:

```
$result = !empty($result);
```

[empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` only not the actual value of the variable's value.

OR,

Change the above line to:

`$result = ! empty($result) ? $result : NULL;`

Comment: You should be using `$result ? $result : null`, `empty` is unnecessary. Of course, that further reduces to `$result ?: null`.

Comment: can you explain this please '$result ? $result : null'